# setting up mod_jk on the Apache HTTP web server2.2.13

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

So I'm trying out JSP for the first time. I found a tutorial that details the installation of the tomcat server and the mod_jk Apache module, but it's a bit outdated. Right now, I've got everything installed and the mod_jk.so file in the modules folder, along with the corresponding loadModule line in the httpd.conf file. The tutorial tells me to copy a file called 'workers.propperties' to the apache conf directory and do some changes inside it, but there's no such file in the win32 binary installation. However, there is a file in the zipped source code, but I'm not sure if I should use it.

I have installed JDK1.6.0U17/JRE6.0/Apache HTTPServer2.2.13/Tomcat6.0.20/Mod_JK1.2.28/Vista

Answer (score 1):

First this question: do you *actually* need Apache HTTP Server for other purposes? If not, just leave it aside and run Tomcat standlone. I've namely seen too often that starters are somehow under the impression that they need *both* Apache HTTP Server and Apache Tomcat to be able to run JSP's. This is untrue. Just Tomcat is enough. It's a webserver and servlet container in one.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Well, I use the apache server for other testing purposes--mainly PHP and MySQL, but I like to test new things, so I like to keep it around.